# Forms Help Password and Confirm Password

Tags: php, database

Thanks for all your help in my previous questions. I have yet another question that I needed help with.

I have developed a form and have two fields called password and confirm password. How do i make sure that Password and confirm password are equal? If they aren't I need to display a message.

Thank You

@richsage - Thanks. I will from now on.

Thank you everyone..

Comment: I realize this question is very old, but I think this should be mentioned: confirming a password should not just be done on the server-side in PHP, but should also be done on the client side using JavaScript.  It's extremely frustrating as a user to fill in a form and submit it, only to have the server tell you "passwords do not match", when that message could have been given to you on the client side instead.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters to a PHP script are always strings, so you can use the equality operator (`==`) to check if the two parameters have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcasecmp()` or `strncasecmp()` function

Comment: Do you really believe that passwords should be case-insensitive?

Comment: Hi, Ingacio. It's up to developer, this is why I posted both functions. Passwords shouldn't be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if ($_GET["password"] != $_GET["confirm_password"]){
  echo "Passwords must match";
}else {
  // do something
}
```